# django rest allauth: activation link expiration

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth, email-verification

I am using **django_rest_auth** and **allauth** for email verification.When the activation link for email is expired or email record is deleted, clicking on activation link sends me to localhost:8000/acccounts/confirm-email/... and tells me that activation link is expired. But i want to redirect the user to my Frontend url when the activation link is expired. How can i do this?
Note that i can redirect the user to my desired url when the activation link works correctly using:
`ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = '127.0.0.1:8000/my/custom/url'`